# Sending ruby 'nil' data to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby, null, sequel

I have a field in MySQL (using Sequel Pro) that is for `tinyint` and allows for `null`. I am trying to send data to it, and right now all the data in Ruby are either `1`, `0`, or `nil`. Yet for some reason, when I send `nil`, I get:

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'blank' at row 1.

How do I get the MySQL gem in Ruby to understand that `nil` means `NULL` and not `''`?

## the code used to determine the values

def num_converter(type)
    for i in 0..$array_of_hashes.length()-1 do
        a = $array_of_hashes[i][type]
        case a
        when "Yes"
            $array_of_hashes[i][type] = 1
        when "No"
            $array_of_hashes[i][type] = 0
        else 
            $array_of_hashes[i][type] = nil
        end

    end

## insert into database is

for i in 1..$array_of_hashes.length()-1 do 
    con.query("INSERT INTO feedback(names of fields)
    VALUES (items from arrays)

to clear things up a bit - it inserts all the numbers into the database but stops once it reaches the nil value - this is when i get the error message - even though I have sequel pro allowing null.  I think it is because it is converting nil into the string ''.  But I do not know how to change this

Comment: You need to show the code you use to determine the value and the code used to insert it into the database. Otherwise we can't tell what you are doing wrong or right.

Comment: FWIW I don't understand the reason for the closure votes except that you haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: Sorry, does that help at all?